# launch an excel file from a Controller using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, excel

What do I need to do to open an excel file via controller action using javascript?
I tried the this way but it does not open the file.

JavaScript Function:

```
function ExcelExport() {

    var link = '/Report/ExcelExportData';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: link,

        success: function (result) {

        },
        error: function (result) {

        }
    });

};
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult ExcelExportData()
        {
            return File("~/Reports/ExcelFile.xlsm", Server.UrlEncode("~/Reports/ExcelFile.xlsm"));

        }
```

Comment: Is a controller necessary for this? Maybe I'm missing something but could you link it with an anchor tag instead?

Comment: @Ant it is a static filepath, file is stored in my project folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can't open files directly from ajax callback responses. You could try two different approaches:

1. Use an anchor for opening the file and get rid of the ajax request. Something like `<a href="/Report/ExcelExportData">` will do.
2. Call `window.open(link)` inside your success callback. The only advantage of this approach is that it allows you to handle unexpected errors (file not found or something like that). It will perform another roundtrip to the server, though.